# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError on Flask WTForm

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have the following errors while displaying related forms for entry.

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError UnmappedInstanceError: Class
>   'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result' is not mapped

here is the `models.py`

```
class Project(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'projects'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(175), unique=True, nullable=False)
description = db.Column(db.Text)
#---------------------------
region = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('regions.id'))
district  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('districts.id'))
subdistrict  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subdistricts.id'))
village = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('villages.id'))
#------------------------------------
baseline = db.Column(db.Text())
performance_indicator = db.Column(db.Text)
budget = db.Column(db.Float())
author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
posted_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
est_completion = db.Column(db.DateTime)
mark_complete = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
activities = db.relationship('Activity', backref='projects', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic')
remarks = db.relationship('Remark', backref='projects', cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic')
beneficiary = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('beneficiaries.id'))
sector =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sectors.id'))
media = db.relationship('Media', secondary=projects_media, backref='projects')

def __init__(self, id, title, description, baseline, performance_indicator, budget, remark, remark_author, author, posted_date, start_date, est_completion, mark_complete):
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.description = description
    self.baseline = baseline
    self.performance_indicator = performance_indicator
    self.budget = budget
    self.author = author
    self.posted_date = posted_date
    self.start_date = start_date
    self.est_completion = est_completion
    self.mark_complete = mark_complete
```

the `forms.py`

```
from flask.ext.wtf.file import FileRequired, FileAllowed, FileField
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from project.location.models import Region, District, Subdistrict, Village
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES, DOCUMENTS
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, NumberRange
from . models import Sector, Project, Activity
from project import db
from project.crc.models import CrC
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, validators, SubmitField, SelectField, IntegerField, DateTimeField, \
RadioField, BooleanField, DecimalField, DateField, FileField
def sector_lists():
    return db.session.query(Sector.name)

def region_lists():
    return db.session.query(Region.region)

def district_lists():
     return db.session.query(District.district)

def sub_districts():
    return db.session.query(Subdistrict.subdistrict)

def villages_lists():
    return db.session.query(Village.village)

def project_lists():
    return db.session.query(Project.title)

def activity_lists():
    return db.session.query(Activity.title)

images = UploadSet('images', IMAGES)


class ProjectForm(Form):
    title = StringField('Project Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Project Details', validators=[DataRequired()])
     sector = QuerySelectField(get_label='Service Sector', query_factory=sector_lists)
     regions = QuerySelectField(get_label='Regions', query_factory=region_lists)
     district = QuerySelectField(get_label='Regions', query_factory=district_lists)
     subdistrict = QuerySelectField(get_label='Subdistrict', query_factory=sub_districts)
     village = QuerySelectField(get_label='Village', query_factory=villages_lists)
     baseline = TextAreaField('Baseline')
     performance_indicator = TextAreaField('Performance Indicator')
     budget = DecimalField("Planned Budget, places'2'")
     started = DateTimeField('Project Started Date')
     estimated_completion = DateField('Estimated Completion date', format='%Y-%m-%d')
     completed = BooleanField('Completed?', default=False)
     media_gallery = FileField('image', validators=[
    FileRequired(),
    FileAllowed(images, "Image Only")
])
```

and finally my `views.py`

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def deliverables():
    forms = ProjectForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and forms.validate_on_submit():
        pmodel = Project(title=forms.title.data,description=forms.description.data, baseline=forms.baseline.data, performance_indicator=forms.performance_indicator.data, budget=forms.budget.data, author='mainuser', posted_date=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), start_date=forms.started.data, est_completion=forms.estimated_completion.data, mark_complete=forms.completed.data)
    db.session.add(pmodel)
    db.session.commit()
return render_template('front/deliverables_edit.html', forms=forms)
```

Comment: `validate_on_submit` checks for POST, you don't need to check for it separately.

Comment: @dirn, thank, i have taken note.

Comment: You can also use the [form's `populate_obj`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/forms.html#the-form-class) method to simplify creating new instances. `pmodel = Project(); forms.populate_obj(pmodel)`. You'd need to change (or remove) `Project.__init__` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The `query_factory` callback should return complete entities, not columns

```
def sector_lists():
    return db.session.query(Sector)

def region_lists():
    return db.session.query(Region)

def district_lists():
     return db.session.query(District)
```

Answer (score 1):

As your code:

```
def sector_lists():
    return db.session.query(Sector.name)
```

You can't return a column to QuerySelectField's query_factory(must return a query), you has specified at QuerySelectField's get_label:

`sector = QuerySelectField(get_label='Service Sector',query_factory=sector_lists)`

And that's enough. You must change function `sector_lists`:

```
def sector_lists():
    return db.session.query(Sector)
```